# Send Password through Email

Tags: java, netbeans

Hey guys here I have a problem..In my java application there is a Login form. In that there is an option "forgot password..?" I want to send the password of the user from that..In that case the email address of the user identify with the user name give..no problem on that.But the problem is passwords are encrypted..How can I get those pwd to default format and send it. My login tabel name is Login and 3 field un,pw,type(admin or limit)..my mail send code is as follows..

```
try{

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com"); // for gmail use smtp.gmail.com
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.debug", "true"); 
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

    Session mailSession = Session.getInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {

        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication("ravinduis34@gmail.com",    "password");
        }
    });

    mailSession.setDebug(true); // Enable the debug mode

    Message msg = new MimeMessage( mailSession );

    //--[ Set the FROM, TO, DATE and SUBJECT fields
    msg.setFrom( new InternetAddress( "ravinduis34@gmail.com" ) );
    msg.setRecipients(    Message.RecipientType.TO,InternetAddress.parse("ravindusisira@gmail.com") );
    msg.setSentDate( new Date(232323));
    msg.setSubject( "Hello World!" );

    //--[ Create the body of the mail
    msg.setText( "Hello from my first e-mail sent with JavaMail" );

    //--[ Ask the Transport class to send our mail message
    Transport.send( msg );

}catch(Exception E){
    System.out.println( "Oops something has gone pearshaped!");
    System.out.println( E );
}
```

Comment: **Do not store passwords in plain text**.  Reversible encryption is (almost) no better.  You _need_ to understand what hashing means.

Comment: Are the passwords encrypted or are they hashed? Encrypted passwords will need to be decrypted using the proper key(s). If the password is hashed, then you will be unable to send the user their password. Instead, you must ask the user to create a new password.

Comment: Security is **hard**.  Do not re-invent the wheel.  Use an existing, proven, authentication package.

Comment: public static byte[] computeHash(String x) 
in my method here it looks

Comment: Its better to create a new password and send the new password to the user. More on the lines of reset password.

Comment: It always worries me if a site can send me the password I set. It means they are storing it in a form they can decrypt. The better sites send a new password, and encourage or require an immediate password change after using it to log in.

Comment: This is a poor question about poor design. Of course people here could help you send a password in email, but you should be using one-way encryption and storing only salted hashes.

Comment: It's no need to send the pwd through email when user allows to create a new pwd..in this situation what should i do to recover pwd..pls heip..I am amateur to java

Comment: **Don't do this**.  If you have to ask this question, you are not capable of creating a secure authentication system (most people aren't).  Use an existing solution.

Comment: You should never recover passwords. Give users a link to RESET their passwords and then salt/hash the new password. One way encryption is the only reasonable solution for passwords.

Comment: I think folks should be voting this question down. I don't want to be mean but this type of design shouldn't be encouraged.

Comment: OK you all say when user forgets his pwd there is an option called forget password..? when user clicks that the password field should empty(null) and give user to create new password..

Comment: Something like that but please talk to a security professional before you implement this.

Comment: I am not a professional in this field just entered to the field..these situations are common to all of the amateur in this field..we can solve our problems from these method and all your help..please be kind to help to people who entered to the field...I think stackoverflow is not a place of talent show..It's a path to the helpless people who suffering from various problems

Comment: Of course and I sympathize with you. Security is just very hard and should be taken very seriously. Good luck.

Comment: hey guys sorry for my ruthless comment..this stupid question will help to other amateur in the field..

Comment: Specifically, it will help you and other amateurs create security holes and leak credit cards.  **Don't do this**!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Passwords are usually not stored in an encrypted form, but rather in the form of the result of applying a [secure one way hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function); best practices also include using a user (or at least system) specific [salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29) to prevent attacks using [rainbow tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table). All of that said, you should probably just set a new (calculable) password for the user and then communicate to them that it is now set to that (e.g. read an employee table, use the last six digits of their ssn and their street address number).